# ionic2 EXCEPTION: jQuery is not defined

Tags: angular, ionic2

i can't include Jquery, tried to do by this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrdHEBkGAow

1) included scripts to Index.html:

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.0.0/jquery-migrate.js"></script>
```

2)

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { RegistrationPage } from '../registration/registration';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})

export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page

  tab1Root: any = HomePage;
  tab2Root: any = AboutPage;
  tab3Root: any = ContactPage;

  constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer:Renderer) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("NG ON CHAN START DATE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    console.log('test ', jQuery(this.element.nativeElement).find('body'));

  }
```

3) test in browser:  ionic serve -l

4) get error **EXCEPTION: jQuery is not defined**

Help please someone